# Why am I getting an "unexpected ')' " error when I try and run my dbt jinja model?

Tags: jinja2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have created a model in DBT to run against Snowflake.  I am using some jinja to iterate through a list of table names, and build some sql for each table.

The following script should loop through each table, generate some SQL script and insert a UNION statement between each piece of script except for the last iteration.

I am getting the following error however I can not see any stray parenthesis

**11:44:23    001003 (42000): SQL compilation error**

**11:44:23    syntax error line 14 at position 6 unexpected ')'.**

My script is

```
{{
config(
    query_tag = 'DBT: Staging_History'  
)
}}

{% set table_names_query %}
select table_name
from information_schema.tables 
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_CATALOG = 'PROD_SOURCE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 
'DIS_STG'
{% endset %}

{% set results = run_query(table_names_query) %}

{% if execute %}
{% set results_list = results.columns[0].values() %}
{% else %}
{% set results_list = [] %}
{% endif %}


{% for table_name in results_list %}
SELECT * FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.copy_history(table_name=>'PROD_SOURCE.DIS_STG.DBO_ORGANIZATION', start_time=>dateadd(DAY, -90, current_timestamp)))
{% if not loop.last %} UNION {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you tried double quotes around values rather than single quotes? Also, to understand what is causing the SQL compilation have a look at Query History via Snowflake UI, you should see how the query looked there when it arrived at Snowflake.

Comment: HI I just tried double quotes but it didnt help, in fact it seemed to introduce new problems

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use the macro of [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_timestamp.html) (aka without the parens) it must be in upper case.

So ether change to

```
current_timestamp()
```

or

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: My original SQL is working in snowflake, but to align with you I have changed it to current_timestamp().  Still though I receive the same error in dbt when I try to run the model.  It suggests the error relates to row 14 which is the blank row between {% set results = run_query(table_names_query) %} and {% if execute %}

Comment: @NickHall The error you are getting is a Snowflake SQL compilation error that usually means you have the wrong syntax. The easiest way to verify this is to use Snowflake's UI [Query History](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html) page. You will see there exactly how the query arrived at Snowflake side and if there is a syntax error or not.